# How to compare two files, if same column then replace , using awk or sed

Tags: awk

Two files:

f1:

```
1 aaa 123
2 bbb 555
3 ccc 666
```

f2:

```
1 aaa 444
2 ddd 666
3 eee 777
```

When f2 has same as f1 like aaa value, then the r1c3 of f2 replace by r1c3 of f1, using awk or sed.

Output:

```
1 aaa 123
2 ddd 666
3 eee 777
```

Thanks

Comment: should the first column also match?

Comment: Nomatter it match or not, aaa is my focus. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$2]=$3; next }{ print $1,$2,( a[$2] ? a[$2] : $3 )}' f1 f2
```

Comment: think how that'd behave if a[$2] evaluated to zero. Use `$2 in a` instead. Also parenthesise the ternary expression for portability.